# Jacoco:: coverage percentage to print on console

Tags: jacoco

After running `mvn jacoco:report` how can We print coverage percentage on console ?

I can see it in browser but want it to print in jenkins.

Answer (score 13):

I got it with below command:

```sh
awk -F, \
    '{ instructions += $4 + $5; covered += $5 } END \
     { print covered, "/", instructions, " instructions covered"; \
     print 100*covered/instructions, "% covered" }' \
    target/site/jacoco/jacoco.csv
```

Comment: For anyone using fish terminal, I had to surround the command section in single quotes to avoid the mismatched brackets error: awk -F, '{ instructions += $4 + $5; covered += $5 } END { print covered, "/", instructions, " instructions covered"; print 100*covered/instructions, "% covered" }' target/site/jacoco/jacoco.csv

Comment: @Marquee Same thing with `bash`, you also need quotes